# Multiple with_items in an Ansible module block

Tags: linux, ansible

I want to create multiple logical volumes with a variable file but it return a sintax error  `found character that cannot start any token`, I have tried in different ways but still doesn't work

main.yml

```
---
- name: playbook for create volume groups
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  tasks:
    - include_vars: vars.yml
    - name: Create a logical volume 
      lvol:
        vg: vg03
        lv: "{{ item.var1 }}"
        size: "{{ item.var2 }}"
      with_items: 
        - { var1: "{{ var_lv_name }}", var2: "{{ var_lv_size }}" }
```

vars.yml

```
var_lv_name:
  - lv05
  - lv06

var_lv_size:
  - 1g
  - 1g
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [*with_together*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-together). Test it first. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Create lv: {{ item.0 }} size: {{ item.1 }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ var_lv_name }}"
        - "{{ var_lv_size }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'Create lv: lv05 size: 1g'
  msg: 'Create lv: lv06 size: 1g'
```

---

Optionally, put the declaration below into the file *vars.yml*

```yaml
var_lv: "{{ var_lv_name|zip(var_lv_size) }}"
```

This creates the list

```yaml
  var_lv:
    - [lv05, 1g]
    - [lv06, 1g]
```

Use it in the code. The simplified task below gives the same results

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Create lv: {{ item.0 }} size: {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ var_lv }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer it's totally correct but In my humble opinion we should be getting into the new way to do the things with `loop` and `filters`.

Here's my answer:

```yaml
---
- name: playbook for create volume groups
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  become: true

  vars_files: vars.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Create a logical volume 
      lvol:
        vg: vg03
        lv: "{{ item[0] }}"
        size: "{{ item[1] }}"
      loop: "{{ var_lv_name | zip(var_lv_size) | list }}"
```

In this answer you're using the new way to use loops with keyword `loop` and using filters like `zip` and turning the result into a `list` type for iteration in the loop.